# Why can't I import the modules?

Tags: python, module

I'm using python 3.7 on MacOS and somehow I can't import certain modules like Flask, Pandas or xldr. When I type in pip3 list all modules are installed. Other modules as np I can easily run...
The editor I use is Atom.

Comment: Are you sure `atom` uses the exact `python3`, and you have installed `flask`, and other modules for that `python3` and not  for some other `python` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your PYTHONPATH? What exactly do you mean when you say that you can't import?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my editor, but I really can't understand why it works in IDLE but not in Atom (I installed the package "script"). When I import something in Atom it says no module found "...", in IDLE everything works.